# Socket io not working on Android 9.0 - io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException xhr poll error

Tags: android, socket.io, android-9.0-pie

I am developing an android app on localhost using Socket io.

I works fine when I test it on android 8.1 and android 4.4.
But when I experimented with Android 9.0, I couldn't connect to localhost.

> Error "io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error".

Note: I don't use SSL

(build.gradle.dependencies)

```
implementation ('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
}
```

Where the error returns

```java
client = IO.socket("http://localhost:3000"); 

...

client.on(Socket.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, new Emitter.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void call(final Object... args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            Log.d(TAG, args[i]);
            // io.socket.engineio.client.EngineIOException: xhr poll error
        }
    }
});

...

client.connect();
```

Comment: "I don't use SSL" -- that is your problem. Cleartext communications are blocked on Android 9.0+ by default: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28#framework-security-changes

Comment: Thank you. But I use "http://localhost:80" for api access, and it working

Comment: The problem was solved by installing ssl. Thank you @CommonsWare